# Where sequelize-cli keeps seeds' list?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize-cli

I created a script which immidiately creates all necesserily files and code lines for model.
So among others my script is creating migration file for model and seed file for model.

With migration file i have no problem - **npx sequelize db:migrate** command executes added files, so tables are created

But with **db:seed:all** situation is different - it executes only files which were added through native sequelize script and ignore all, that were created by my script...So i suspect that i should register them somewhere...

If i am right please show me that magic place.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am an idiot, execution just stucked in the middle because of of the seeds didnt return an answer, otherwise it works well